# Play Framework 2.1.3 Form's fillAndValidate not processing global errors

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm having trouble identifying some weird behavior while using `fillAndValidate` on a Form. Here is the simplest use case I could think of to isolate the issue:

```scala
object Application extends Controller {

  case class SimpleForm(val field: String)

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "field" -> text.verifying("message", (s: String) => false)
    )(SimpleForm.apply)(SimpleForm.unapply))

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    println("bindFromRequest: " + form.bindFromRequest.errors)
    println("fillAndValidate: " + form.fillAndValidate(SimpleForm("value")).errors)

    Ok
  }
}
```

When requesting the index page with the query `?field=value`, I'm getting the following on the console:

```scala
bindFromRequest: List(FormError(field,message,WrappedArray()))
fillAndValidate: List(FormError(field,message,WrappedArray()))
```

Which is, as far as I know, the expected behavior.

However, when using global errors, such as verifying the mapping directly:

```scala
val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "field" -> text
  )(SimpleForm.apply)(SimpleForm.unapply)
  .verifying("message", (s: SimpleForm) => false))
```

The behavior I get is quite surprising:

```scala
bindFromRequest: List(FormError(,message,WrappedArray()))
fillAndValidate: List()
```

Why is `fillAndValidate` ignoring the error? Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Good question, but I think it must be asked in play group. Looks like global errors are not clever idea, or at least badly implemented